# Why is the GUI not displayed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

What is the problem with this code?
the GUI is not displaying. This is the GUI for a 4x4 picture memory for my lab project.
any help would be appreciated .

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class memory extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    String pictures[]
            = {"riven1.jpg", "riven2.jpg", "riven3.jpg", "riven4.jpg", "riven5.jpg", "riven6.jpg", "riven7.jpg", "riven8.jpg"};

    JButton button[];

    public memory() {
        Container c = getContentPane();
        setTitle("Memory Game");
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            button[x] = new JButton(new ImageIcon(pictures[x]));
            c.add(button[x]);
            button[x].addActionListener(this);
        }
        setSize(700, 700);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new memory();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"..the GUI is not displaying"*  Do you mean the frame does not appear, the content of the frame does not appear, or something else?  I can see (several reasons) why the 2nd might happen, but not the first.

Comment: You do realize the `panel` needs to be added to the frame or content pane (`c`) in order to appear, right?  Now that I look more closely at that code, I realize it does not even ***compile.***  That might be a big factor.

Comment: the whole doesnt appear the general output tells this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at memory.<init>(memory.java:18)
 at memory.main(memory.java:33)

Comment: the whole window i mean :(

Comment: See edit to my 2nd comment, and please stop wasting our time talking about a run-time problem, while posting code that never gets that far.

Comment: it will compile because i added the buttons on the Container.. the problem is when i run the program that shows on the general output and the whole window doesnt appear

Comment: *"it will compile.."*  My compiler says different.  `error: cannot find symbol. symbol:   variable panel`  Strange as it may seem, I trust the compiler's assessment over yours.

Comment: i guess frame might be showing but the contents not , right ??

Comment: That you are getting a NullPointerException could be useful information to include in the question, don't you think? Also: seems like you mean to be calling `setLayout` on `c`, seeing as how `panel` doesn't refer to an existing variable.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of problems...

First: You never initialise `button[]`

```
JButton button[];

public memory() {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    setTitle("Memory Game");
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        button[x] = new JButton(new ImageIcon(pictures[x]));
```

This will cause a `NullPointerException`, as `button` defaults to `null` and hasn't been initialised

Initialise button before the for-loop, for example...

```
button = new JButton[16];
```

Second: You're adding all your buttons to the content pane, whose default layout is BorderLayout. This means that only the last button you add will be visible, occupying the entire window.

Try setting the layout manager of the content pane...

```
c.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
```

Third: `panel` is undefined, so your example shouldn't even compile

```
 // I have no idea how this is defined...
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
```

Side notes: Avoid using `setSize` where you can, instead use `pack`. This takes into account differences between how different platforms might render things like fonts. You should also ensure that state of the window is set before you make it visible

```
    // Use pack instead
    //setSize(700, 700);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
```